# PrimeFaces 6.2 Grid CSS sample

Tags: css, primefaces

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

 <h:head>
  <title>PrimeFaces Test</title>
 </h:head>
 <h:body>

  <h:form>
   <style type="text/css">
.ui-g div {
background-color: #ededed;
text-align: center;
border: 1px solid #fafafa;
}
</style>

<p:outputPanel>

<h3 style="margin-top: 0">Basic</h3>
<div class="ui-g">
<div class="ui-g-1">1</div>
<div class="ui-g-1">1</div>
<div class="ui-g-1">1</div>
<div class="ui-g-1">1</div>
<div class="ui-g-1">1</div>
<div class="ui-g-1">1</div>
<div class="ui-g-1">1</div>
<div class="ui-g-1">1</div>
<div class="ui-g-1">1</div>
<div class="ui-g-1">1</div>
<div class="ui-g-1">1</div>
<div class="ui-g-1">1</div>
</div>

<div class="ui-g">
<div class="ui-g-2">2</div>
<div class="ui-g-2">2</div>
<div class="ui-g-2">2</div>
<div class="ui-g-2">2</div>
<div class="ui-g-2">2</div>
<div class="ui-g-2">2</div>
</div>


<div class="ui-g">
<div class="ui-g-3">3</div>
<div class="ui-g-3">3</div>
<div class="ui-g-3">3</div>
<div class="ui-g-3">3</div>
</div>


<div class="ui-g">
<div class="ui-g-4">4</div>
<div class="ui-g-4">4</div>
<div class="ui-g-4">4</div>
</div>

<div class="ui-g">
<div class="ui-g-6">6</div>
<div class="ui-g-6">6</div>
</div>

<div class="ui-g">
<div class="ui-g-12">12</div>
</div>

<div class="ui-g">
<div class="ui-g-4">4</div>
<div class="ui-g-8">8</div>
</div>

<div class="ui-g">
<div class="ui-g-3">3</div>
<div class="ui-g-9">9</div>
</div>

<div class="ui-g">
<div class="ui-g-3">3</div>
<div class="ui-g-5">5</div>
<div class="ui-g-4">4</div>
</div>

<div class="ui-g">
<div class="ui-g-4">4</div>
<div class="ui-g-2">2</div>
<div class="ui-g-2">2</div>
<div class="ui-g-3">3</div>
<div class="ui-g-1">1</div>
</div>

<h3>Responsive</h3>
<div class="ui-g">
<div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-6 ui-lg-3">ui-g-12 ui-md-6 ui-lg-3</div>
<div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-6 ui-lg-3">ui-g-12 ui-md-6 ui-lg-3</div>
<div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-6 ui-lg-3">ui-g-12 ui-md-6 ui-lg-3</div>
<div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-6 ui-lg-3">ui-g-12 ui-md-6 ui-lg-3</div>
</div>

<div class="ui-g">
<div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-6 ui-lg-4">ui-g-12 ui-md-6 ui-lg-4</div>
<div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-6 ui-lg-4">ui-g-12 ui-md-6 ui-lg-4</div>
<div class="ui-g-12 ui-lg-4">ui-g-12 ui-lg-4</div>
</div>

<h3>Nested</h3>
<div class="ui-g">
<div class="ui-g-8 ui-g-nopad">
<div class="ui-g-6">6</div>
<div class="ui-g-6">6</div>
<div class="ui-g-12">12</div>
</div>
<div class="ui-g-4">4</div>
</div>

<h3>Sample Layout</h3>
<div class="ui-g">
<div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-2">Menu</div>
<div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-10 ui-g-nopad">
<div class="ui-g-12">
Bar
</div>
<div class="ui-g-12 ui-g-nopad">
<div class="ui-g">
<div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed imperdiet, orci nec dictum convallis, ligula mauris vestibulum turpis, nec varius tortor quam at diam. Nullam a viverra nibh. In tincidunt tempor lectus quis vulputate. Pellentesque nec dui aliquam, lobortis est in, lobortis ante</div>
<div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-4">Maecenas vel nisi aliquet, vulputate tortor id, laoreet massa. Maecenas mattis tristique bibendum. Suspendisse vel mi dictum, vestibulum lacus quis, pulvinar quam. Proin vulputate, nibh at finibus varius, leo eros lacinia elit, nec blandit odio tellus a justo. Donec nec ex auctor, tristique nulla nec, rutrum sapien.</div>
<div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-4">Proin efficitur in leo eget ornare. Nam vestibulum neque sed velit sagittis sodales. Sed scelerisque hendrerit magna a hendrerit. Cras tempor sem at justo pharetra convallis. Curabitur vel sodales purus. Vestibulum interdum facilisis nulla imperdiet suscipit. Quisque lectus felis, condimentum eget hendrerit sit amet.</div>
</div>

<div class="ui-g">
<div class="ui-g-6 ui-md-3"><p:graphicImage name="demo/images/nature/nature1.jpg" style="width:100%"/></div> 
<div class="ui-g-6 ui-md-3"><p:graphicImage name="demo/images/nature/nature2.jpg" style="width:100%"/></div> 
<div class="ui-g-6 ui-md-3"><p:graphicImage name="demo/images/nature/nature3.jpg" style="width:100%"/></div> 
<div class="ui-g-6 ui-md-3"><p:graphicImage name="demo/images/nature/nature4.jpg" style="width:100%"/></div> 
</div>

<div class="ui-g">
<div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-6">Phasellus faucibus purus volutpat mauris lacinia sodales. Ut sit amet sapien facilisis, commodo dui non, fringilla tellus. Quisque tempus facilisis nisi sodales finibus. Pellentesque neque orci, ullamcorper vitae ligula quis, dignissim euismod augue.</div>
<div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-6">Fusce ullamcorper congue massa, eget ullamcorper nunc lobortis egestas. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque ultrices dui eget dolor feugiat dapibus. Aliquam pretium leo et egestas luctus. Nunc facilisis gravida tellus.</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="ui-g-12">
Footer
</div>
</div>
</p:outputPanel>
  </h:form>

 </h:body>
</html>
```

[image]I'm using PrimeFaces 6.2 in an Eclipse project. The Grid CSS sample doesn't work. I tested the following [sample](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/grid.xhtml).

The right result would be like [this](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/grid.xhtml). I used the same code sample by PrimeFaces. My result is not responsive. Where is my error? 
My container is tomcat 9.0.

Using internal eclipse web browser is ok.[image: Sample on Firefox or Chrome. Bad.]

Below the web.xml

1. http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" >

   ```
   <context-param>
       <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
       <param-value>server</param-value>
   </context-param>
   <context-param>
       <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
       <param-value>Production</param-value>
   </context-param>

   <context-param>
       <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
       <param-value>aristo</param-value> <!--          <param-value>mytheme</param-value> -->
   </context-param>
    <!--     <context-param> --> <!--         <param-name>primefaces.FONT_AWESOME</param-name> --> <!--
   ```

   true -->  -->

   ```
   <servlet>
       <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class> <!--
   ```

   solo mia app ** no test -->
           1

   ```
   <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>

   <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>

   <mime-mapping>
       <extension>ttf</extension>
       <mime-type>application/font-sfnt</mime-type>
   </mime-mapping>
   <mime-mapping>
       <extension>woff</extension>
       <mime-type>application/font-woff</mime-type>
   </mime-mapping>
   <mime-mapping>
       <extension>woff2</extension>
       <mime-type>application/font-woff2</mime-type>
   </mime-mapping>
   <mime-mapping>
       <extension>eot</extension>
       <mime-type>application/vnd.ms-fontobject</mime-type>
   </mime-mapping>
       <mime-mapping>
       <extension>eot?#iefix</extension>
       <mime-type>application/vnd.ms-fontobject</mime-type>
   </mime-mapping>
   <mime-mapping>
       <extension>svg</extension>
       <mime-type>image/svg+xml</mime-type>
   </mime-mapping>
   <mime-mapping>
       <extension>svg#latobold</extension>
       <mime-type>image/svg+xml</mime-type>
   </mime-mapping>
   <mime-mapping>
       <extension>svg#latoblack</extension>
       <mime-type>image/svg+xml</mime-type>
   </mime-mapping>
       <mime-mapping>
       <extension>svg#latolight</extension>
       <mime-type>image/svg+xml</mime-type>
   </mime-mapping>
   <mime-mapping>
       <extension>svg#latoregular</extension>
       <mime-type>image/svg+xml</mime-type>
   </mime-mapping>
   <mime-mapping>
       <extension>svg#fontawesomeregular</extension>
       <mime-type>image/svg+xml</mime-type>
   </mime-mapping>

   <welcome-file-list>
       <welcome-file>init.xhtml</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>
    <!--   no test *** solo mia app   -->   <session-config>
   <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>   </session-config>
   ```

   javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext
       resources.application   
        
       com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener

[image: css debug with chrome]

Comment: I added the code html/primefaces page to test. It seems that using firefoz does not run css code primeface.

Comment: Why did you create a new question???? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55413375/primefaces-6-2-grid-css

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PrimeFaces 6.2 Grid CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55413375/primefaces-6-2-grid-css)

Comment: I wrong to post the first question. I deleted it ....This  is the correct question.

Comment: I tested my problem. I m using eclipse Neon.3 Release (4.6.3), tomcat 9.0, primefaces6.2.  I start the tomcat container

Comment: Tried PF 7.0? That is what is in the showcase

Comment: I tested my problem on pf 7.0 too.
I m using eclipse Neon.3 Release (4.6.3), tomcat 9.0, primefaces6.2.
-I start the tomcat container;
-On eclipse I set web browser-->firefox;
-On load the sample the page is OK! On refresh or reloading the page is KO!

So:
- I stop/restart the container server;
-On eclipse I set web browser-->chrome;
-On load the sample the page is OK! On refresh or reloading the page is KO!

Setting web browser while the container server is up,and reload the page, does not work.

It's very strange ....

Help me!

Comment: Then debug... network traffic etc... showcase does not have this, I do not have this, so if it works intermittently, it most likely is networl related

Comment: I'm facing this same issue with PF 8.0. I haven't tried other versions.